# How to return multiple users objects with single API call?

Tags: support, api

I am using the following to return JSON of a user object:

`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/8826629?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&key=<my key>`

I need multiple user objects so currently I am making multiple API calls which slows down the application. Is there an endpoint I can use that takes multiple user IDs as arguments so I can get multiple users from a single GET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the API methods that take an `id` can actually take upto 100 IDs that are semicolon-delimited.

See the [user/{ids}](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids) docs that states:

> {ids} can contain up to 100 semicolon delimited ids.

So you can simply do something like `8826629;3541881`:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/8826629;3541881?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&key=<my key>
```

At the moment, that would return something like the following, with the `items` array containing user objects:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "badge_counts": {
      "bronze": 31,
      "silver": 11,
      "gold": 1
    },
    "account_id": 4337810,
    "is_employee": false,
    "last_modified_date": 1532268715,
    "last_access_date": 1532542525,
    "reputation_change_year": 182,
    "reputation_change_quarter": 12,
    "reputation_change_month": 12,
    "reputation_change_week": -8,
    "reputation_change_day": 0,
    "reputation": 1678,
    "creation_date": 1397662172,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "user_id": 3541881,
    "accept_rate": 100,
    "location": "The Intersect",
    "website_url": "http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/shub",
    "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/3541881/%e1%94%95%e1%96%ba%e1%98%8e%e1%95%8a",
    "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBmQb.png?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name": "ᔕᖺᘎᕊ"
  }, {
    "badge_counts": {
      "bronze": 14,
      "silver": 1,
      "gold": 0
    },
    "account_id": 12071398,
    "is_employee": false,
    "last_modified_date": 1528510828,
    "last_access_date": 1532540206,
    "reputation_change_year": 358,
    "reputation_change_quarter": 0,
    "reputation_change_month": 0,
    "reputation_change_week": 0,
    "reputation_change_day": 0,
    "reputation": 459,
    "creation_date": 1508862010,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "user_id": 8826629,
    "location": "Seattle, WA, USA",
    "website_url": "",
    "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/8826629/joel-guerra-msft",
    "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU7EG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name": "Joel Guerra - MSFT"
  }],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 300,
  "quota_remaining": 295
}
```

[Here's a working link :)](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/8826629;3541881?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow) (without `key`)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed